# How to call a jar file from a java program using relfection api

Tags: java, parsing, jar, etl

i have an application which parse some file which is in zip format and results some csv files.So now i have a requirement that i have to make a jar file from the application and call that jar from a java program so that it can do the same work as it is used to.So my application program have the following structure  i am attaching pic of it...[image: my skybin parser]

I am trying to use reflection api a to do the work ,basically i am trying to load the reckoner class dynamically.In my approach i think it is loading the class,because if i misspell the class name it is giving error.But when i am writing this code and trying to run
nothing is happening.i am trying the next code..

```
public class Driver {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{

        ClassLoader myClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
          String classNameToBeLoaded="com.gamma.Reckoner";
          Class myClass = myClassLoader.loadClass(classNameToBeLoaded);
          Object whatInstance = myClass.newInstance();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

so when i will make jar of it can try to call it from another program the directory structure should be there..so have made according to the actual skybin parser.Now how i will call the jar.please help me.I have to call the Reconer.java class of the skybin.jar which is the driver of the application.So using reflection can i call it

Comment: What do you mean by "call JAR file"?

Comment: i mean i want to call a .jar i.e skybin.jar sorry if i am unclear

Comment: put your jar in class path and call the any class of jar file. "call JAR file" seems meaning less

Comment: it is not working for me i have tried the same way you told

Comment: you should be more clear. 1. do you want to make a jar of your current classes? That way you can give your program to others as a single .jar file OR do you want to zip the results? Or what

Comment: see my skybin is a parser which parse some files from a  specific source and return the result to a destination.I have a class name Reckoner in the skybin which acts as the main class,now i have to make a skybin.jar and use the .jar file not the whole application,to do the same work..please tell me if i am unclear....

Comment: does anyone have any idea how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible answer, really not sure what your asking. looks like you have a jar and want to know how to run it?

How did you get that jar? Maven/ ant? IDE cliks?

Anyway from comment line:

1. if jar is at c:\prjs\skybin\skybin.jar
2. open a cmd prompt, cd to that folder

> cd c:\prjs\skybin\
>
> give command 
>   java -cp c:\prjs\skybin\skybin.jar com.gamma.Reckoner
>
> If Reckoner does not have a package then
>
> java -cp c:\prjs\skybin\skybin.jar Reckoner

java should be in classpath else give full path like

> c:\program files\etcjava\v77\bin\java -cp c:\prjs\skybin\skybin.jar Reckoner

This is a sample path on your computer might be different or add the java bin folder to path

Do a few tutorials on starting java and using jars

If on linux/ mac need to use / in paths and not \

To find out of your jar is made properly can un jar it.

1. In command prompt make a new dir

   mkdir c:\prjs\tmp2
2. cd to that and give command

jar xf c:\prjs\skybin\skybin.jar

now check the output in explorer should see your package strcture and classes inside it, no extra folders
Per your image you should see com/gamma/mail and other folders like that

Comment: not sure what you want. if its another class you want to call just refer to it and call it. If you dynamically want to load a jar you can do that and use reflection. but your really not clear what your requirement is. anyway whatever i just spoke about you can get from google so maybe search a bit more

Comment: so if i use the reflection api for dynamic loading of the skybin Reckoner class will my problem be solved

Answer (score 0):

You can add your jar in your Classpath :
http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29